# NullPointer Exception when trying to Unit Test using SpringRunner

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, jdbctemplate, springrunner

Hi I am trying to run my unit test using `SpringRunner.class`. I am creating a new instance for jdbcTemaplte in my test class. I am using H2 DB for unit test and i am able to use the jdbcTemplate instance to create or update the tables.It works fine. but when it goes to the actual class its testing the jdbcTemplate is null which throws `NullPointerException`

Below is the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyClassTest {

@InjectMocks
private ClassToTest classToTest;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
static class Config {

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate orderService() {
        BasicDataSource dataSourceConfig = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceConfig.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db");
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername("someUserName");
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword("somePassword");

        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceConfig);
    }
}
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
//Use the jdbcTemplate to create Queries in H2 which works fine.
}

}
```

**ClassToTest.java**

```
 public class ClassToTest{
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   //someMethod in DAO using jdbcTemplate to make sql Operations.

}
```

the JDBC Template is null in ClassToTest and throws a nullPointerException when trying to test the method.

I am just not sure why the Autowire is not wiring the dependency i have created. I have tried to use @Primary to explicitly take this jdbcTemplate when necessary but not sure why its not working.

Any suggestions are helpful here. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You’re using @InjectMocks annotation on your object under test but you’re not mocking anything, instead you want to load spring context and inject the jdbcTemplate bean into it. Try to replace @InjectMocks with @Autowired on ClassToTest and remove jdbcTemplate field. jdbcTemplate bean should be initialized in Config and be autowired into ClassToTest. Also you might want to specify the Config class in @ContextConfiguration. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I see many factors that could be in cause :

- Your class "ClassToTest" isn't a Spring service/component, the autowire cannot work. Why won't you annotate it with @Component ?
- Good practices with Spring advice to put autowires in the constructor.

Like :

```
@Component
public class ClassToTest {
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired // Although it's not even required when you have only one constructor : it's by default autowired
    public ClassToTest(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
}
```

Try this, tell us what worked. Good luck